# Missing @InitializeRecord

Tags: delphi-7, pascal, delphi

I am working on a delphi 7 project with a minimalistic system.pas /sysinit.pas
When I try to use records in my project my compiler brings this error:

```
System unit out of date or corrupted: missing '@InitializeRecord'
```

Since I am trying to program in pure pascal / no RTL is there a way to manually enable/call the Initialization for the records?!

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let's see if I've got this right. You've modified system.pas and sysinit.pas and want us to help you debug it. But we can't see the code. Is that it?

Comment: there's no code needed. I just started a new console project, defined a new record and try to debug/set a value from the record and it fails to compile. Debug would be nice too, so I can just cooy & paste whatever I need.

Comment: When I start a new console project, the compiler handles records just fine.

Comment: That means you have non-standard system unit somewhere.
Check IDE and Project search paths.
Check your disk for all files system.* Use SysInternals ProcessMonitor to check which system.dcu or system.pas is actually used during compilation attempt

Comment: That was my purpose to use modified system / sysinit. I just need to initialize the records.

Comment: Then there is a question, did you downloaded some non-standard RTL or did you modified stock one makign your own RTL. If former - then look their documentation how to re-enable the aforenamed procedure. If latter - you should know how to re-enable it, since it was you who disabled it.

Comment: I used the minimalistic from delphibasics.info this system.pas makes sure that you can only use compiler commands and vars, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi compiler relies on some "intrinsic functions", which are called by the generated code.

For instance, when you define a `record` in your code, the Delphi compiler will generate a call to `InitializeRecord`, even if you do not use any RTL. This is the same for `string` and dynamic array handling.

So you won't be able to by-pass and ignore those functions, since they are expected to exist by the compiler itself.

Delphi is not meant to strip down the low-level RTL units. I've done that in some cases:

- For our [LVCL units](http://synopse.info/fossil/dir?name=LVCL) (similar to your expections), our [enhanced RTL files](http://synopse.info/forum/viewforum.php?id=6) can be compiled especially to be stripped down when LVCL conditional is defined;
- For [DWPL-based projects](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dwpl/), targeting DOS with the Delphi compiler;
- The [TORO kernel](http://torokerneleng.blogspot.fr).

*FreePascal* is much better when down-stripping the system units. Since it targets even [embedded systems](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Embedded), you can optionally strip string support, FPU, or even whole heap process.

Comment: Add one more System-replacement to the list - http://kolmck.net/
That was what i used to make 2KB DLL with Delphi5 :-)

Comment: I can't test any code right now but all I need is the "raw" rtl source. (no vcl). I might go with free pascal, cause I really don't need much. I'll check your links asap. Thank you.

Comment: What does InitializeRecord actually do? I thought that variables that weren't object properties were uninitialized (undefined) at runtime.

Comment: @RobertFrank, managed types like string,array of xxx, etc are initialized.

Comment: @RobertFrank `InitializeRecord` will be called for stack-allocated records (this is not necessary for records in a dynamic array or in a `class`, which are already zeroed). It will use the record RTTI to identify all reference-counted variables (string/variant/dynamic arrays/interface) within this record, and set them to nil / ''. Other members will stay undefined. I guess a plain fillchar() could most of the time be  faster today that using the RTTI in a loop, but it was implemented as such since Delphi 1, and old implementation pattern remains. See its code in System.pas.

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss it has an optional modular replacement RTL. Did you really looked into their download section ?

Comment: @Arioch'The If you compile our enhanced RTL files in Delphi 7 with the LVCL conditional, the resulting System.dcu + SysInit.dcu will be even smaller and faster than the one supplied in KOL. And you have "light" version of Classes.pas / SysUtils.pas and such.

Comment: @Arnaud, KOL also had classes/sysutils though they are 404 right off.
But i am not for comparision for two reasons. 1) i no more use D5 and switched to XE2. 2) KOL replacement was modular so you could IfDef selected features. This makes the question of dcu size a bogus one - the only way to answer is to make 2^N vector of sizes, which is hardly practical for comparison.  I did not tell if their work was superior or inferior to yours. I just noted that u're making a list and consider them worth mentioning for list being complete. PS frankly, it seems 2 me u're a bit jealous or negative 2 them.